# JSON problema on nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am having a problem with the object in javascript passed parameter to the NodeJS.

When I create the object inside the function:

```
 var obj = {host: 123,
            port: 456}
```

and give a ws.send(obj.host) it returns me 123.

However, when I do the following:

```
function a(param) {
    var obj = param;
    ws.send (obj.host);
}

a({host: 123, port: 456});
```

it returns me undefined

The code is:

```
var http      = require("http");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var mysql     = require('sequelize').mysql;
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.end("WS port:1337");
});

server.listen(1337, function() { });

var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server });

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

ws.on('message', function(message) {
    ws.send(exec(message));
});

function exec(msg) {
    var cmd = msg.split(':')[0].toLowerCase(); //Get the first string before ':' and all cmd begin with 3 letters.
var message = '';

for(i=4; i<msg.length; i++) {
    message += msg[i];
}
console.log("Cmd type: " + cmd);

switch(cmd) { //send 'msg:' type the message after ':'.
case 'msg' :
    return message;

case 'sql' : //send to another function the object message like {host: 'x.x.x.x', port: xxxx, user...}
sql(message);
return 'res:';
break;

    default:
        return "not defined!";
    }

}   
});
```

Comment: typo, `:` missing on the host param?

Comment: have, but i made ​​a mistake when typing here

Comment: *What* returns undefined? `a`? There's no return statement anywhere.

Comment: ws.send(obj.host); returns undefined

Comment: obj['host'] too no avail

Comment: Post a more complete code snippet. Your bug is probably not what you think it is but I suspect by simplifying your code to post here you are omitting relevant pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

When you send JSON via websocket, you should transform your string to JSON before send. 
This function, JSON.stringify(str), may help you.
Of course, when the server receives this message, you should change it back to array.